# Node.js How to add wkhtmltopdf result to PDFKit page?

Tags: node.js, wkhtmltopdf, node-pdfkit

Is there a way to concat the result of an an html page converted with wkhtmltopdf-node inside a document page created with pdfkit in node.js, instead of just creating a pdf file from html?

```
const doc = new PDFDocument({
  bufferPages:true,
  toc: true,
  margins: {
    top: 125,
    bottom: 50,
    left: 50,
    right: 50
    }
});
    

doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));

doc.addPage();
doc.text("HTML Content ")

// concat the result of this conversion inside doc instead of out.pdf
wkhtmltopdf(params.content, { pageSize: 'letter' }).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.pdf'));
```

Something like

```
doc.concat(wkhtmltopdf(params.content, { pageSize: 'letter' }));
```